# URL query part composition and decomposition

Tags: java, url, encoding

What's the preferred/recommended way to hande the query part of URLs like:

```
(?)attr=value&attr=value2&attr2=value
```

Specificially the conversion between `Map<String,String>` and query string url encoded form. Is there any sane implementation that takes care of encoding special chars like & and =? How about "=" in the attr name? Are there any related RFCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URI templates.

[This library](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) does exactly that. Example quoted from the README:

```
# Substitution of a map of query parameters
http://foo.bar.com/some/request{?queryparams*}

# "queryparams" associative array:
hello -> world!,
streetInGerman -> Straße

# result of expansion:
http://foo.bar.com/some/request?hello=world%21&streetInGerman=Stra%C3%9Fe
```

The related RFCs are RFC 3986 (URI) and RFC 6570 (URI templates).

---

For decomposition, it is a little harder; you can use the `URI` class to parse your URI, and then grab the query string. But you will still have to split the result by yourself.